# Cannot find namespace 'ng'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, electron

I am rewriting simple angular 1.6 project to typescript. I have declared typings dependencies and they are compiled and installed. Despite that there is compilation error "Cannot find namespace 'ng'" in my service.
Angular name is also not recognized.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTpf1.png)

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "files": [
        "app/**/*.ts",
        "app/**/*.js",
        "main.js",
        "renderer.js"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowJs": false,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "typeRoots": ["./typings"] 
    }
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.6.0+20170321201455"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20170310222111"
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
module Services {

    export interface IMyService {
    }

    export class MyService {

        http: ng.IHttpService;
        location: ng.ILocationService;

        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService, $location: ng.ILocationService) {
            this.http = $http;
            this.location = $location;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you should add `angular` types to `tsconfig.json` as following:

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions":
        ...
        "types": [
            "angular"
        ],
}
```

If that won't work, since `typings` are deprecated, I suggest you to install `@types/angular` with npm:

`npm install --save-dev @types/angular`

and include it as above.

Cheers.

Comment: >npm install --save @types/angular
and
import angular = require("@types/angular");

fixed issue, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Add below `package npm`.

`npm install --save-dev @types/angular`

then include the following line on top of the .ts file:

`import * as angular from "angular"`.

It will solve error. thanks.